# Al escribir URL con slash "/" al final, dentro de mi proyecto laravel 8.4, me redirige hacia https://www.dominio.com/var/www/dominio.com/public/slug

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, laravel-8

Mi proyecto está en laravel 8.4, al agregar "/" al final de cada ruta, me redirige hacia: "http://www.dominio.com/var/www/carpeta_Proyecto/public/slug, mi opción sería agregar un archivo .htaccess dentro de la carpeta public, pero no tengo mucho conocimiento sobre creación de archivo .htaccess, alguien me podría ayudar a resolver este problema con htaccess u otra manera,
El pryecto se encuentra dentro de servidores de IONOS, linux apache.

Ejemplo:
al agregar slash al final a la URL:
https://www.dominio.com/tienda-on-line/
me redirije hacia [www.dominio.com/var/www/public/tienda-on-line](http://www.dominio.com/var/www/public/tienda-on-line) (cualquier slug)

Estuve investigando y probe con este código, pero no resulto:

```
RewritEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: cual es el efecto deseado?

Comment: muestra como tienes las url